# How to populate Django form dynamically with a dictionary of lists and dictionaries?

Tags: django, forms, dictionary, dynamic, django-jsonfield

I've been stuck on this for over a day now and was hoping I could get some help. I've read a bunch of different SO posts and `Django` docs on forms, formsets, bound and unbound forms, but still cant figure this out.

I'm pulling in some data from a model which is a `JSONField`. It's a nested mess of dictionary (dict) like so:

```
 dict= { 
    'A':'data1',
    'B': [ {
       'one': [
          {'x': 'data2', 'y': 'data3', 'z': 'data4'}, 
          {'x': 'data5', 'y': 'data6', 'z': 'data7'},
          {'x': 'data8', 'y': 'data9', 'z': 'data10'}
        ],
       'two':'val', 
       'three': { 
         'color':'red',
         'size':'big',
         'order':'new'
         },
       'four':'someVal',
      }],
   'C':'moreData'
  }
```

The inner list, **one**, will have a dynamic amount of dictionaries in it, in this example, there are just 3. The key's for **one** will always be the same (x, y, and z), but the values will change.

I need to create an editable form, that has each key in it's own charfield with the initial data set as the value.

I've looked into and tried some packages (`django-entangled`, `django-json-widget`, `django-SplitJSONWidget-form`..), but haven't had any luck.

I've tried both bound and unbound forms. The closet I got was taking this approach:

```
# MODEL: 

class myModel(models.Model):
    foo = JSONField(blank=True)

# ===========================================================
# FORM: 

class oneForm(forms.Form):
   A = CharField()
   B = CharField()
   C = CharField()


class twoForm(forms.Form)
   two = CharField()
   four = CharField()

# for one(list):
class triForm(forms.Form):
   x = charField()
   y = charField()
   z = charField()

# for three(nested-dict):
class fourForm(forms.Form):
   color = CharField()
   size = CharField()
   order = CharField()

# ===========================================================
# VIEW:

def myView(request,pk):

    # getting value of model.Field(JSONField)
    obj = myModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
    myJson = getattr(obj,'foo')

    # Get count of list(one) because it'll dynamically change (this example = 3)
    list_count = len(myJson['B'][0]['one'])

    # Dynamically populate lines:
    one_list = [myJson['B'][0]['one'][i] for i in range(list_count)]


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = oneForm(initial=myJson) # for first level of dict. 
        form2 = twoForm(initial=myJson['B'][0]) # for second level of list. 
        form3 = triForm(initial=one_list) # for one list
        form4 = fourForm(initial=myJson['B'][0]['three']) # for three dict.

        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            # Haven't even got around to try and reformat all the data and save it... 

            data.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blah:home', args=(pk,)))

    else:
        form = oneForm(initial=myJson) # for first level of dict. 
        form2 = twoForm(initial=myJson['B'][0]) # for second level of list. 
        form3 = triForm(initial=one_list) # for one list
        form4 = fourForm(initial=myJson['B'][0]['three']) # for three dict.

    return render(request, T, {

        'form': form,
        'form2': form2,
        'form3': form3,
        'form4': form4,
        'range': range(list_count),
    })
# ===========================================================

# TEMPLATE: 

... some html / form tags

{{ form.as_p }}
{{ form2.as_p }}
{{ form3.as_p }}
{{ form4.as_p }}

... closing tags
```

This route get's me the correct data fields and initial inputs, although it will not dynamically populate the inner-list (one). It will only display the first dictionary.

x [    data2    ] 
y [    data3    ] 
z [    data4    ]

... and I tried running it through a {% for x in range %}, but it would just reprint the above 3 times without getting the different values (data 5,6,7,8,9,10).

Any info or tips would help!

Comment: there are some  "," and ";" which are misplaced. If you you are using same JSON, this may be the problem.

Comment: That was my mistake in manually writing some demo JSON for the post. Just edited it, thanks for the catch!